# One form three pages. How to pass state between them?

Tags: angular

**My goal:**
I want to let the user to create a new object, let's say a car. It is divided into three steps/pages/views:

1. Information about the car - form with inputs (First page `<app-car-create-page1></app-car-create-page1>`)
2. Information about the current owner - form with inputs (Second page `<app-car-create-page2></app-car-create-page2>`)
3. Information about the new owner - form with inputs (Third page `<app-car-create-page3></app-car-create-page3>`)

**The problem:**
How to pass form data from `app-car-create-page1` to `app-car-create-page2` and from `app-car-create-page2` to `app-car-create-page3` ?

**My apporaches:**
For me the easiest way was to use `state` object and implent it this way:
*Page1*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-car-create-page1',
  templateUrl: './car-create-page1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./car-create-page1.component.scss']
})
export class CarCreatePage1Component implements OnInit {

  carInformationFormGroup = this.fb.group({
    brand: [''],
    model: [''],
    mileage: ['']
  });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  private navigateToNextPage() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/cars/create?pageNr=2',
      {state: {page1FormData: this.carInformationFormGroup}});
  }
}
```

*Page 2*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-car-create-page2',
  templateUrl: './car-create-page2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./car-create-page2.component.scss']
})
export class CarCreatePage2Component implements OnInit {

  private state$: Observable<object>;

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.state$ =  this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(e => e instanceof NavigationStart),
      map(() => this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state)
    );


  }
}
```

What gives me:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': function () { return _this._updateDomValue(); } could not be cloned.
        Error: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': function () { return _this._updateDomValue(); } could not be cloned.
            at BrowserPlatformLocation.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.BrowserPlatformLocation.pushState (platform-browser.js:610)
            at PathLocationStrategy.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.PathLocationStrategy.pushState (common.js:498)
(...)
```

according to other online posts, it's related to the problem with serialization. What probably could solve a problem is [safe json stringify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/safe-json-stringify).
Another solution to my main problem is to use [ngx-navigation-with-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-navigation-with-data).

And truth be told, I am the beginner at the frontend so it's not easy for me to make a right decision, hence my question.

1. Is my approach even correct for that case ?
2. What should I do to pass form data from one component to another ?
3. I've read about the approach with creating a service class, that is supposed to be injected in both components and get data from there. But that is definitely not for my case.

Comment: Maybe just use a simple shared service for storing the data for all these pages.

Comment: Just create service add it to AppModule and instantiate it from each component.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via services:

**service.ts**

```
private variable = new BehaviorSubject('default val');
varToSend = this.variable.asObservable();

connectVariable(message){
    this.variable .next(message);
}
```

**page1.ts**

```
this.service.connectVariable(varToSend)
```

**page2.ts**

```
this.service.varToSend.subscribe(message => {this.varInPage2= message});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CarService {

  public get car () {
    return this._car.asObservable();
  }
  public set car (next) {
    return this._car.next(next);
  }
  private _car = new BehaviorSubject({});


  constructor() { }
}
```

// Now you can change the value of car's object like so

```
export class CarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private carService: CarService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // change the value
    this.carService.car = newValue;

    // subscribe for changes
    this.carSer
  }

}
```

Comment: why not just call it a CarFormService and build the form there?